# More power, more plasma?

Tags: science-fiction, weapons, energy

So in looking into plasma tech for a book, I looked at plasma cutters. Multiple articles I read suggested that after inverting, the input power requires around 13.4kw at around 80 amps to turn an argon/hydrogen 65/35 gas mix into plasma that hovers around 20-22 thousand degrees Celsius.

Assuming all things required to hold and fire said plasma at an enemy are taken care of, what happens if I were to double the input power to 26.8kw and 160 amps? Does the plasma get hotter or as one "article" said does the plasma retain the extra electrical energy as some type of plasma battery?

Comment: I definitely recommend searching "plasma" on this site.  The long and the short of it: plasma makes a terrible weapon.  It doesn't go far, it doesn't carry energy well, and it is outclassed by other weapons in practically every respect.  If you're looking for a realistic plasma weapon, there isn't one.

Comment: Also, without a flow rate (generally PSI) for the gas mix, the wattage required is kind of meaningless.

Comment: @jdunlop can you provide a link that shows why plasma is a terrible weapon? I would like to know more about this topic.

Comment: @EkadhSingh - as I said, searching this site is an excellent resource, but to get you started, there's [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22312/handheld-weapons-plasma-vs-laser/22314#22314), [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/57460/36850), [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/147479/36850), [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/97805/36850)...

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know plasma doesn't have ways to store energy: what the source producing it puts into it, goes into energy of the components.

When I used RIE (Reactive Ion Etching) to clean samples in my university year, we could play with the composition of the plasma (e.g. by picking an oxygen plasma or an argon plasma) and with the energy of the plasma to achieve the desired result. In the same way you can poke or vigorously scrub a pan and have different effects on its cleanliness, the same applied with plasma.

More or less this is what you are doing: more energy you put in the plasma, more energy will the plasma have in terms of "agitation" of its components for the same mass.